# Logging in to meetup.com with Curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to automatically log in to www.meetup.com without much success:-

This is my code:-

```
      <?
$username="my@email.com";
$password="123abc";
$url="http://meetup.com";
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$postdata = "email=". $username ."&password=". $password . "&submitButton=Login";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "/login");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.meetup.com/");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

exit;
?>
```

No joy - any ideas?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 3):

they may be handing you a session cookie upon first pageload

try making a request with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and then make the login request using CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR

also for the hell of it, this is a function i make to make requests look cleaner

```
function curl_http_request ($url, $options)
{
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);
    ob_start();
    $buffer = curl_exec($handle);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($handle);
    return $buffer;
}
```

example of use

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
);

curl_http_request($url, $options);
```

this should work

```
// set global curl options
$curloptions = array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://www.meetup.com/'
);

// set userinfo
$username = 'bobsmit@gmail.com';
$password = 'bobsmit@gmail.com';
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';

// clear cookie.txt (fresh session)
$handle = fopen($cookie, 'w');
fclose($handle);

// make a dummy request to generate a session
curl_http_request('http://www.meetup.com/login/', $curloptions);

// login
curl_http_request('http://www.meetup.com/login/', 
    array(
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'email=' . urlencode($username) . '&password=' . urlencode($password) . '&rememberme=on&submitButton=Login&returnUri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.meetup.com%2F&op=login',
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE
    ), $curloptions
);

//example request
echo curl_http_request('http://www.meetup.com/account/', 
    array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
    ), $curloptions
);

function curl_http_request ($url, $moreoptions = array(), $options = array())
{
    foreach ($moreoptions as $k => $v) $options[$k] = $v;
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);
  ob_start();
  $buffer = curl_exec($handle);
  ob_end_clean();
  curl_close($handle);
  return $buffer;
}
```

hope this one works :)

Comment: Thanks Chad, I tried (at least I think I did it correctly) to add the line you suggested but no joy. I would be very grateful if you can perhaps try it out for yourself with www.meetup.com and let me know if you can get it to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: the above works for me, like i said they use a session. So to successfully login you will need to make a dummy page request with CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR file set to make the site give you session cookies. Then actually post a login. :)

Comment: Hi Chad - awesome!

That worked a treat with one smallish issue. when I try and navigate to another page it loses the login.

Is there a way to retain the login status? For example I run the script from http/mydomain.com/testlogin.php which is successful and displays the meetup page but if I click on a link it goes to http://meetup.com/link-I-clicked but not with me logged in.

Any ideas?

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Please use `$url=https://secure.meetup.com` and replace the line `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.meetup.com/");`   by `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "");`

So it will work...