# Use referrer info to get image from url

Tags: php, image, curl, gd, gif

Hi I want to get image from another site but I requires referrer information to show image.

image address is: http://www.foo.com/hist.gif?21918+201020
this adress show gif image if you came this page from foo.com
Think I can do this with curl but I don't know how to do this.

I have to show image with img tag

Comment: if they require a referer - they **do not want** their pictures shown on the other sites.

Comment: this site do not want to show everyone, but they said we use referrer to get this images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CURLOPT_REFERER option.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842498/logging-in-to-meetup-com-with-curl/842502#842502) for some sample code.